# How do I conditionally set a css style based on its children elements?

Tags: html, css

I have a class that is used in multiple `div`s

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="child1">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="child2">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="child3">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Here, I want to add a style (let's just say `color: red`) to the `wrapper` class that has `child2` as its child. I want to do this based on the name, not the order of the child. Any thoughts?

Comment: Javascript. CSS doesn't have a way to alter the ancestor of a targeted element.

Comment: Possibly something like `document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper').forEach(wrapper => wrapper.querySelector('.child2') ? wrapper.classList.add('color-me-red') : null)`

Comment: The only possible way to influence a parent from it's descendant  using only CSS relies on user interaction and specific types of elements, events, markup, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you can only achieve the behaviour you want using JavaScript.

Use JavaScript to select all `.wrapper > .child2` elements and set the style of the parent wrapper element to what you want.

However, it might eventually be possible with CSS thanks to the [:has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo-class. It is not currently supported by any major browsers but that could change soon!